# CSS menu not aligned correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jYSYW/

I would like to put the pink menu at the bottom right of `header .container`. I did try to use `position: relative;` and `aboslute` but wihtout success...

Any clues ?

I also want *NOT* to apply the ul/li css to the bootstrap dropdown if possible.

Thanks

PS: This is a shortened version of my theme.

Comment: @Mr_Green Haha, no pink is there just so it's easy to see. I'll change the color in the future !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added

```
header .container{
   height: 80px;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}

nav.pull-right {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

and it works.
here is a new fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dMu5y/

Answer (score 1):

[Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/rJgGw/) :)

Added:

```
 .container nav.pull-right {
     position: absolute;
     right: 0;
     bottom: 0;   
 }    
 .container {
       position: relative; 
       width: 100%; 
       height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, it's working but not as expected. If you look carefully, you'll see that the pink menu is on the far right side of the container. Container is not suppose to be fluid but fixed size and your position relative change everything.. it's in the bootstrap.